# Pygame game loop syntax

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a doodle jump-style game. This code only includes the platforms, and the start screen. I need the game loop to finish my button function, at the start screen.
How do I make a game loop/define a game loop, in my code? I keep getting syntax error saying my game loop is not defined.

My code:

```
import pygame as pg
import sys,time,random
pg.init()
res_x,res_y=800,600
screen = pg.display.set_mode((res_x,res_y))
screen.fill((0,0,0))
pg.display.update()
clock=pg.time.Clock()

#COLOURS
light_green=(124,252,0)
green=(50,205,50)
light_red=(255,99,71)
red=(128,0,0)
yellow=(255,215,0)
black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)
light_grey=(119,136,153)
dark_pink=(220,20,60)
light_pink=(255,108,180)
sky_blue=(0,255,255)

#start screen
def text_object(text, font,):
        textsurface=font.render(text,True,(255,255,255))
        return textsurface, textsurface.get_rect()

def button(msg1,x1,y1,l1,h1,ic1,ac1,action=None):
        mouse=pg.mouse.get_pos()
        click=pg.mouse.get_pressed()

        if x1+l1>mouse[0]>x1 and y1+h1>mouse[1]>y1:
            button_start=pg.draw.rect(screen,ac1,(x1,y1,l1,h1),)
            if click[0]==1 and action!= None:
                if action=='play':
                    game_loop()


        else:
            button_start=pg.draw.rect(screen,ic1,(x1,y1,l1,h1),)

        smalltext=pg.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',30,)
        textsurf, textrect= text_object(msg1,smalltext)
        textrect.center=((x1+(l1/2)),(y1+(h1/2)))
        screen.blit(textsurf, textrect)




def start():
    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
             if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill((119,136,153))
        bigtext=pg.font.SysFont('arial.ttf',100)
        textsurf,textrect= text_object('Maze Runner',bigtext)
        textrect.center=((res_x/2),(res_y/2))
        screen.blit(textsurf,textrect)

        button('GO!',110,400,200,50,green,light_green,'play')
        button('QUIT',450,400,200,50,red,light_red,'quit')

        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
start()

#platform
rect_x=random.randrange(0,200)
rect_y=random.randrange(50,120)
rect_l=300
rect_h=50

rect1_x=random.randrange(230,430)
rect1_y=random.randrange(150,300)
rect1_l=random.randrange(50,200)
rect1_h=50

rect2_x=random.randrange(430,550)
rect2_y=random.randrange(300,450)
rect2_l=100
rect2_h=50

rect3_x=random.randrange(630,750)
rect3_y=random.randrange(450,500)
rect3_l=50
rect3_h=50

def game_loop():
    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    pg.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        screen.fill(black)
        base=pg.draw.rect(screen,sky_blue,(0,540,800,60), )
        platform=pg.draw.rect(screen, yellow, [rect_x,rect_y,rect_l,rect_h],5)
        platform1=pg.draw.rect(screen,white,[rect1_x,rect1_y,rect1_l,rect1_h],5)
        platform2=pg.draw.rect(screen,dark_pink,[rect2_x,rect2_y,rect2_l,rect2_h],5)
        platform2=pg.draw.rect(screen,light_pink,[rect3_x,rect3_y,rect3_l,rect3_h],5)

        pg.display.update()
```

Comment: what is the error? Do not paraphrase the error message, just show it as it is.

Comment: i showed the code that gave me the error

Comment: Please add the complete error message (under `Traceback (most recent call last):`) when you ask a question because that makes it easier for others to understand the problem and to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NameError: name 'game_loop' is not defined` gets raised because you call `game_loop()` in the `button` function before you define it with `def game_loop()`. Just define the `game_loop` function before you call `start()` and subsequently `button()`.

```
def game_loop():
    # Code omitted.

start()  # Call start() afterwards.
```